# Pandas: how to format both rows and columns when exporting to Excel (row format takes precedence)?

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am using pandas and xlsxwriter to export and format a number of dataframes to Excel.

The xlsxwriter documentation mentions that:
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html?highlight=set_column

```
A row format takes precedence over a default column format
```

**Precedence means that, if you format column B as percentage, and then row 2 as bold, cell B2 won't be bold and in % - it will be bold only, but not in %!**

I have provided an example below. **Is there a way around it?** Maybe an engine other than xlsxwriter? Maybe some way to apply formatting after exporting the dataframes to Excel?

It makes no difference whether I format the row first and the columns later, or viceversa.

It's not shown in the example below, but in my code I export a number of dataframes, all with the same columns, to the same Excel sheet. The dataframes are the equivalent of an Excel Pivot table, with a 'total' row at the bottom. I'd like the header row and the total row to be bold, and each column to have a specific formatting depending on the data (%, thousands, millions, etc). Sample code below:

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
wk = writer.book.add_worksheet('Test')

fmt_bold = writer.book.add_format({'bold':True})
fmt_pct = writer.book.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%'})

wk.write(1,1,1)
wk.write(2,1,2)

wk.set_column(1,1, None, fmt_pct)
wk.set_row(1,None, fmt_bold)

writer.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

As @jmcnamara notes openpyxl provides different formatting options because it allows you essentially to process a dataframe within a worksheet. NB. openpyxl does not support row or column formats.

The openpyxl `dataframe_to_rows()` function converts a dataframe to a generator of values, row by row allowing you to apply whatever formatting or additional processing you like.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it's me, but these points were not exactly clear in the documentation of neither openpyxl nor xlsxwriter.
Specifically, I find it misleading to say that precedence is like in Excel, because in Excel you can apply formatting without removing the existing one, e.g. if column B is formatted as %, you can select row 2, make it bold, and B2 will be bold and in %. You cannot do this with these packages, so, no, they do not mimic Excel

Comment: I need to look into the win32com module. Reformatting every single cell one by one would be a pain. I'm hoping I can export to Excel and apply column formatting with xlsxwriter, then reopen the same file and apply row formatting with win32com.

Comment: Whichever way you do it, formatting is **always** cell by cell; the row and column formatting suggested by Excel is misleading. win32com is slow, better to use xlwings, but named styles in openpyxl are fast.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you will need to create another format that is a combination of the row and column formats and apply it to the cell.

In order to do that you will need to iterate over the data frame and call XlsxWriter directly, rather then using the Pandas-Excel interface.

Alternatively, you may be able to do using OpenPyXL as the pandas Excel engine. Recent versions of the Pandas interface added the ability to add formatting to the Excel data after writing the dataframe, when using OpenPyXL.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you mean that, I need to apply the formatting cell by cell? In other words, there is no way to just say: column B in %, row 2 in bold, and have B2 in bold and %, the way I'd do if I were to open the file in Excel manually?
Instead, I need to come up with a script that sets: B2: bold and %, C2 bold only, B3: % only, etc. 

Also, when you say iterate, do you mean iterate to apply the formatting, or write the dataframe cell by cell instead of relying on the to_excel() method?

Comment: You say that OpenPyXL lets you add formatting after writing the dataframe,but I am already doing that with XlsxWriter, so I'm a bit confused. I export the dataframe to excel using the to_excel() method with xlsxwriter as the engine, then use set_format() and set_column to apply formatting to the dataframe I have already exported to Excel.

Comment: PS Or maybe I could use the win32com module to control Excel from within Python? Basiclaly what I want is to mimic what happens when you use Excel manually, which is to add, not replace formatting.

Comment: *"I need to apply the formatting cell by cell?"* Yes. *"here is no way to just say..."*. Correct. *"do you mean iterate to apply the formatting, or write the dataframe cell by cell"*. Yes, you will need to write the data cell by cell if you want to use XlsxWriter.

Comment: *... but I am already doing that with XlsxWriter, so I'm a bit confused.* OpenPyXL allows you to add formatting to cells separately from writing data. XlsxWriter doesn't, you must write the data and the format at the same time. See also [Pandas doc on Excel styles](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Export-to-Excel)

Comment: So, in other words, OpenPyXL can format data it hasn't written, XlsxWriter can't. Is this right?

Comment: No quite. OpenPyXL can format data/cells, after it (or Pandas using OpenPyXL) has written them.  AFAIK, but you should check the documentation.